# NoMethodError `sources' for #<Stripe::Customer with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

When I try to receive data from Stripe customers I get the error undefined method 'sources'.

This is the code that I use:

```
    def update_payment 
    
    if !current_user.stripe_id
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        email: current_user.email,
        source: params[:stripeToken]
      )
    else
      customer = Stripe::Customer.update(
        current_user.stripe_id,
        source: params[:stripeToken]
      )
    end


    if current_user.update(stripe_id: customer.id, stripe_last_4: customer.sources.data.first["last4"])
      flash[:notice] = "New card is saved"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Invalid card"
    end
    redirect_to request.referrer
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:alert] = e.message
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end
```

The output from the customer variable isn't empty, so I don't understand how this error is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sources` is no longer provided by default in the Stripe API since it's a deprecated integration path: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object?lang=ruby#customer_object-sources

You need to explicitly state that you want the `sources` parameter to be returned by expanding it. E.g.

```
cust = Stripe::Customer.create({
  email: 'example@test.com',
  source: 'tok_visa',
  expand: ['sources']
})

// cust.sources is now populated
puts cust.sources
```

Answer (score 0):

The sources attribute is now optional.
And for you to include sources as part of the response, you need to expand it.
Add the sources field to Stripe Create Customer.

Example:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
 email: current_user.email,
 source: params[:stripeToken],
 expand: ['sources']
)
```